# Setup a WLAN to LAN bridge (fedora 22)

Tags: fedora, gnome3, bridge

I would like my computer to (sometimes) act like network bridge. Meaning, when connected to my wifi, I'd like to connect another client (or even switch) to my lan port. (DHCP and NAT enabled, only IPv4 needed).

I've tried to achieve this using Gnome's NetworkManager - no luck.
I've also done `brctl addbr br0`, `brctl addif br0 wlp3s0 enp0s25` but no luck.

Can anyone please point to a guide? thanks!

Comment: Linux doesn't bridge wifi adapters unfortunately.  You could use Internet Connection Sharing instead.  In Network Manager add a new Ethernet connection and set the IPv4 Method to 'Shared to other computer'. You may have to tweak that slightly as I'm on KDE, not Gnome, but the principles are similar.

Comment: What you are describing is what I tried to do before. It didn't work, I may try it again. Why is bridging a WIFI adapter not possible? Has it something to do with authentication? No ways around it?

Comment: I believe it's something to do with the way the kernel drivers are written, but I'm no expert. I'm sure somebody else could explain better. Internet Sharing generally works very well, so you shouldn't come across too much problems.

Comment: Can you describe the "no luck" in more detail?